# Edit my Sites broken on Android

Tags: bug, android-app

They show up super far apart for some reason, I have 3 here but can only see one at a time because of this. Sorry if this isn't the right place for this, I didn't really know where else to report it.

Screenshot:

> [image]

EDIT: Actually I think a video would explain this better: https://youtu.be/IKvTDCkRN88

Comment: Ah, it does seem that this has already been reported. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries, it happens. Some time it is difficult to find the dupe when we are post the question.